# Windows CD or DVD for Lenovo when faced with broken website

Tags: windows, lenovo-laptop, reinstall

I'm trying to acquire or purchase a CD or DVD for a [Lenovo Ideapad 100s](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/100-series/100s-11-inch/). The machine came with Windows 10, but it was blown away during testing other OSes.

Lenovo has a knowledge base article on how to do it at [HT035659: How can I get a Product Recovery CD, DVD or USB from Lenovo](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht035659). The HT035659 page says:

> A. How can I get the recovery media CD, DVD or USB ?
>
> Europe, Middle East, Africa (EMEA) region please visit this online
>   portal to place a request
>   https://www.lenovorecovery.com/Extranet/Home.aspx.
>
> Other regions [contact the support
>   center](https://support.lenovo.com/my/en/contactus).

I'm in the Americas, and following the ***contact the support center*** link takes me to a product search page. The product search page does not appear to provide any of: (1) instructions to order the CD or DVD; (2) email information to request one; or (3) phone number information to request one.

I'm hoping someone has navigated the [apparently broken] process in the past, and can help fill in the missing steps.

How does one acquire or purchase the Windows CD or DVD for Lenovo when faced with the broken website?

Comment: What is unclear about what I am asking? Ramhound, is that you? The downvote and irrelevant reason has all your earmarks...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care for the bundled rubbish that Lenovo put on their recovery media, just get the [official Microsoft ISO file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and burn it to DVD. If you can't do DVDs, you can create a bootable USB Key from the ISO using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)). Of course, you'll need a working internet-connected PC to do this.

Activation is based on a licence that is permanently embedded within the laptop's BIOS, which is why this method works (it has done so since Windows 8.x).

As far as hardware drivers are concerned (for audio, graphics, etc.), Windows 10 will automatically download and install those when you connect to the internet. Then, if you want some Lenovo-specific app, you can download said app from Lenovo's website later. Personally I stay away from those silly apps.

Have fun!

Comment: *"If you don't care for the bundled rubbish..."* - yes, I would prefer to avoid it. But I would also like to get it from Lenovo since Lenovo is the OEM, and they preinstalled it way back when.

Comment: @jww Actually I'm not surprised to find even Lenovo now recommends that you use Microsoft's ISO's (https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht103742) Quote: *...On a working PC, go to the Microsoft software download website to create installation media for the version of Windows you want to install...* Anyway, up to you which way you want to go ;-)

Comment: Lol... Good find for the HT103742 article. The HT035659 article does not say that. I despise webmaster, their broken content, and their broken links. That's their job but they can never seem to execute it.

Comment: @jww I've purchased a few Lenovos in the past, and I agree, their website just doesn't seem to work all that well. In comparison, HP and Dell have been good (IMO). Lucky for Lenovo they make awesome laptops, worth the trouble!